# SumProduct in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sumproduct

I am trying to count the cells in range where the length of the cell is less than 2.

Regular formula "sumproduct(n(len(A2:D10)<2))" works as expected. while trying to incorporate this in my code

```
if [sumproduct(n(len(A2:D10)<2))] <> 0 then 
else
end if
```

it works, but the problem is that range is not fixed so whenever i try to assign a variable and run it is not working shows Error 2029

```
if [sumproduct(n(len("A2:D" & lrow)<2))] <> 0 then 
else
end if
```

anyway to get around this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: `application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(x,y,z)` for example

Comment: You might want to look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba

Comment: What is the value of `lrow`?

Comment: You will need to use `worksheets().Evaluate() ` instead `[]`

Comment: `if ActiveSheet.Evaluate("sumproduct(n(len(A2:D" & lrow & ")<2))") <> 0 then `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Scott -

I thought Activesheet was not needed so i used []

```
ActiveSheet.Evaluate("sumproduct(n(len(A2:D" & Lrow & ")<2))")
```

Now i have modified this as per my requirement I was able to overcome my problem.

Thanks a lot.